# Counting the occurrences of a String in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, variable-assignment

I'm using an ArrayList to save the name, day and time of a show. My program requires me to output the number of shows that play on each day of the week. I've inputted 4 different shows, two of which are on the same day. So far, the only thing the output's given me is "On Thursday there are/is 2 show(s)." The other two didn't show. How can I make is so that it displays the number of shows for each day I've inputted? Here's my code for that:

```
    String showDay = ((showInfo)show.get(0)).day.toString();
    int totalShows = 0;

    //print occurences for how many shows play each day
    for (int i = 0; i < show.size(); i++) {
           if (showDay.equals(((showInfo)show.get(i)).day.toString())) {
                totalShows++;
           }
      }

      System.out.println("On " + showDay + " there are/is " + totalShows + " show(s).");
 }
```

Here's my code for the shows I input:

```
//input information
    do{
        showInfo temp = new showInfo();

        System.out.print("Enter the name of show: ");
        String showName = br.readLine();
        temp.name = showName;

        System.out.print("Enter which day of the week a new episode premieres: ");
        String showDay = br.readLine();
        temp.day = showDay;

        System.out.print("Enter time in 24-hour format (e.g. 2100, 1900): ");
        int showTime = Integer.valueOf(br.readLine()).intValue();
        temp.time = showTime;

        show.add(temp);            

        System.out.print("Would you like to add another show? (y/n) ");
    }
    while((br.readLine().compareTo("n")) != 0);
```

Keep in mind that I'm using Java 1.4. No other choice. By teacher's demand.

This is probably obvious, but I'm being oblivious right now. Any help would be great! Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

```
String showDay = ((showInfo)show.get(0)).day.toString();

    if("sunday".equalsIgnoreCase(showDay)){
        showdayCount[0]++;
        System.out.println("There are/is " + showdayCount[0]++ + " show on Sunday.");
    }else if("monday".equalsIgnoreCase(showDay)){
        showdayCount[1]++;
        System.out.println("There are/is " + showdayCount[1]++ + " show on Monday.");
    }else if("tuesday".equalsIgnoreCase(showDay)){
        showdayCount[2]++;
        System.out.println("There are/is " + showdayCount[2]++ + " show on Tuesday.");
    }else if("wednesday".equalsIgnoreCase(showDay)){
        showdayCount[3]++;
        System.out.println("There are/is " + showdayCount[3]++ + " show on Wednesday.");        
    }else if("thursday".equalsIgnoreCase(showDay)){
        showdayCount[4]++;
        System.out.println("There are/is " + showdayCount[4]++ + " show on Thursday.");
    }else if("friday".equalsIgnoreCase(showDay)){
        showdayCount[5]++;
        System.out.println("There are/is " + showdayCount[5]++ + " show on Friday.");
    }else if("saturday".equalsIgnoreCase(showDay)){
        showdayCount[6]++;
        System.out.println("There are/is " + showdayCount[6]++ + " show on Saturday.");
    }
```

This is also only giving me one line. What am I doing wrong?! :(

**EDIT:**

What I want is to input name/day/time of a TV show, then later be able to display the amount of shows that are on that specific day!

For example, Big Bang Theory and Community are both on Thursday. So the code would output something like

```
There are 2 shows on Thursday.
```

Nothing's worked, so far.

Comment: That old school teacher do not want to update His JDK because he doesn't understand anything at all!

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: Why aren't you using getters and setter methods? Why not use `getDate()`, have it return a String and compare it with the day of the week desired?

Comment: `System.out.println("On " + showDay + " there are/is " + totalShows + " show(s).");` This is only called once. How can you expect it to print the other two?

Comment: @peeskillet Heh, yeah, well I'm not sure how exactly I'd have the loop look!

Comment: I really have to ask this question: Why in this world is the teacher making you write Java 1.4 code? Why? They are doing a disservice to you.

Comment: @John It's an online course and his lesson plans are over a decade old. I made a program in 1.7 but he sent it back telling me to make it work on 1.4. So I had to change it all. It's a pain in the ass.

Answer (score 0):

You only get one day from this line:

```
String showDay = ((showInfo)show.get(0)).day.toString();
```

Here's my hack solution (may have some errors, like a misnamed variable but you should be able to fix it):

```
 //Create a map that maps days to the shows that are on that day
 LinkedHashMap showDays=new LinkedHashMap(); //String to Set map
 String[] days={"Sunday","Monday", ....};//put the rest of the days in here
 for(int dayIndex=0;dayIndex<days.length;dayIndex++){
     String day=days[dayIndex];
     showDays.put(day,new HashSet());
 }

 //iterate through the shows and put them in their respective days in the map
 for (int i = 0; i < show.size(); i++) {
     String dayForShow=((showInfo)show.get(i)).day.toString();
     showDays.get(dayForShow).put(show.get(i));
 }

 //now print out how many shows are on each day
 for(int dayIndex=0;dayIndex<days.length;dayIndex++){
     String day=days[dayIndex];
     int showsToday=showDays.get(day).size();
    ///do your print out now
 }
```

You can make 'LinkedHashMap showDays' a class variable and add to it each time you add to show (and remove from it each time you remove from show).

PS. Tell your teacher it is no longer 2002, technology moves on and they make my job harder.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Show` class

```
public class Show {
    String showName;
    String showDay;
    int showTime;
    static int[] showdayCount = new int[7];

    public Show(String showName, String, showDay, iny showTime){
        this.showName = showName;
        this.showDay = showDay;
        this.showTime = showTime;

        // increment showDayCOunt[] according to showDay from 
        switch(showDay){
            case "Sunday": showDayCount[0]++; break;
            case "Monday": showDayCount[1]++; break;
            case "Tuesday": showDayCount[2]++; break;
            case "Wednesday": showDayCount[3]++; break;
            case "Thursday": showDayCount[4]++; break;
            case "Friday": showDayCount[5]++; break;
            case "Saturday": showDayCount[6]++; break;

        }

    }
}
```

Here's your main method from YourClass

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    // Create Array of Shows
    Show[] shosList = new Show[4]; // or how many ever shows you have

    // Get your inputs for showName, showDay, showTime
    Sting showName = 
    String showDay = 
    int showTime = 


    // Create show Object
    Show show = new Show(showName, showDate, showTime);

    // add show to ArrayList
    showList[someIndex] = show;

    // Do all other stuff then print
    // when you print, you can get the showDayCount directly from the Show class

}
```

Now I don't want to do everything for you.  I just want to get you headed in the right direction.  Note that if you want the above to happen more than once, consider putting inside of a loop.

**Edit: With getShowdayCount**

Add this to my above Show class

```
public int getShowdayCount(String showday){
    switch(showDay){
        case "Sunday": return showDayCount[0]; break;
        case "Monday": return showDayCount[1]; break;
        case "Tuesday": return showDayCount[2]++; break;
        case "Wednesday": return showDayCount[3]++; break;
        case "Thursday": return showDayCount[4]++; break;
        case "Friday": return showDayCount[5]++; break;
        case "Saturday": return showDayCount[6]++; break;

    }
}
```

**Edit:**  With example `if/else if` from `switch` statement

```
// for main method inputs
if ("sunday"equalsIgnoreCase(showDay){
    showdayCount[0]++
} else ("monday".equalsIgnoreCase(showDay){
    showdayCount[1]++
} // finish if/else if statement


// for getShowdayCount method
if ("sunday"equalsIgnoreCase(showDay){
    return showdayCount[0];
} else ("monday".equalsIgnoreCase(showDay){
    return showdayCount[1];
} // finish if/else if statement
```

You can call it from your `main` class like this

```
show.getShowdayCount(show.showday);
```

**Edit:**  Actually, Just put the above edit in you class with the `main` method

```
YourClassWithMainMethod{

    static int[] showdayCount = new int[7];        

    public static void mina(String[] args){

        // call getShowdayCount here
        getShowdayCount(String showday);
    }

    public static int getShowdayCount(String showday){

    }
}
```

**Edit: What you do want and what you don't want**

You dont need this in you if statement

```
 System.out.println("There are/is " + showdayCount[5]++ + " show on Friday.");
```

When you want to print all the shows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < showdayCount.length; i++){
    int showday;

    if (i == 0){
       showday = "Sunday
       finish the if/else if statements
    }
    System.out.println("There is " + showDayCount[i] + " shows on " + showday);

}
```

Comment: He's using Java 1.4, and so generics cannot be used. He will have to cast.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels If I was him, I'd use the NIO classes just to spite the teacher.

Comment: Thank you! But I do have a class. Not sure how I'd incorporate it. Isn't there a way I can fix what I've done to make it work? And yeah, generics are a no-go... @John Wouldn't want to spite my teacher. My exam's on Monday!

Comment: @Sal, see my edit.  you can implement YOUR `showinfo` class with an array like I did, and just add a method to it like i did in my edit

Comment: @Sal, I didn't see exactly what you were trying to do until now.  Take a look at my last edit

Comment: @Sal just use an if statement, works the same.  `if("thursday".equalsIgnoreCase(showDay){showdayCount[4]++}`.

Comment: @Sal in the `getShowdayCount()` - `if("thursday".equalsIgnoreCase(showDay){ return showdayCount[4]}`

Comment: @Sal, I update last couple edits to show example `if/else if` from `switch`

Comment: @peeskillet Could you check my answer? I've edited it to include the if/else! It's still not working and I'm getting frustrated... :(

Comment: @Sal, see my bottom edit.  You need to loop to get multiple outputs.

Comment: @Sal, now that I think about it, I may not even be understanding you desired chronological order of events. Could you clarify in your post.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40445/discussion-between-sal-and-peeskillet)

Comment: @peeskillet I've edited the answer! Hopefully that's what you wanted for clarification?

Comment: @Sal, sorry power went out.  All you have to do is put everything inside of your `do/while` loop.  Put the `if` statement you wrote inside of your `do` block